# Efficiently reshaping data from wide to long format and combining multiple columns into new variables

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have to reshape a dataset that consists of observations (obs) and elements (p) that are linked to the observations. The data (characteristics) of the elements are in new columns attached to the observations.

A MWE looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(obs_id = c(1:3),
                   char1 = sample(1:10, 3),
                   p1 = 1,
                   p1_char = sample(11:20, 3),
                   p2 = 2,
                   p2_char = sample(11:20, 3),
                   p3 = 3,
                   p3_char = sample(11:20, 3))
```

Which results in a data that looks as follows:

```
> data
  obs_id p1 p1_char1 p2 p2_char1 p3 p3_char1
1      1  1       20  2       12  3       16
2      2  1       16  2       20  3       11
3      3  1       18  2       16  3       13
```

`obs_id`are the observations. `pX` indicates the various elements, and `pX_charX` the characteristics.

Now, I have to create the data in a long format with **two** new columns. The first one should be named `p` and contain all element numbers. So, for so good. This can e.g., be easily achieved with `gather` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

data_long1 <- gather(data, key = p_variable, value = p,
                     p1, p2, p3)
```

Filtering out the first observations, everything is should be:

```
> data_long1 %>% filter(obs_id == 1)
  obs_id p1_char1 p2_char1 p3_char1 p_variable p
1      1       20       12       16         p1 1
2      1       20       12       16         p2 2
3      1       20       12       16         p3 3
```

Now, the second new column should be named `char` and be filled with characteristics of the elements. I can stack them independently with gather, too.

```
data_long2 <- gather(data, key = char_variable, value = char,
                     p1_char1, p2_char1, p3_char1)

> data_long2 %>% filter(obs_id == 1)
  obs_id p1 p2 p3 char_variable char
1      1  1  2  3      p1_char1   20
2      1  1  2  3      p2_char1   12
3      1  1  2  3      p3_char1   16
```

Now, I could combine the two with `bind_cols()` to get what I want

```
data_long <- bind_cols(data_long1, data_long2)

> data_long %>% 
+   select(obs_id, p, char) %>% 
+   filter(obs_id == 1)
  obs_id p char
1      1 1   20
2      1 2   12
3      1 3   16
```

The problem is that I would need to do this for every new variable of the elements that I want to stack on top of each other.

**My question is this:** Is there a more efficient way to create two or more columns when I format the data from wide to long? What if I have a `pX_char2` variable in the original data that I want to transform in a `char2` variable in the final data?

Comment: Take a  look at the new `{tidyr}` function `pivot_longer()` and the `names_pattern` (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#many-variables-in-column-names). I'm not so familiar with them but this could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @domaeg points out in the comments, this can be accomplished with the new `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr 1.0.0`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% pivot_longer(-obs_id, 
                      names_to = "p", 
                      names_pattern = "p([0-9])", 
                      values_to = "char")
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  obs_id p      char
   <int> <chr> <int>
1      1 1        20
2      1 2        12
3      1 3        16
4      2 1        16
5      2 2        20
6      2 3        11
7      3 1        18
8      3 2        16
9      3 3        13
```

For good measure, I couldn't reproduce your data with the seed, so I set it up directly like this, if anyone else wants a shot:

```
txt <- "obs_id p1 p1_char1 p2 p2_char1 p3 p3_char1
1      1  1       20  2       12  3       16
2      2  1       16  2       20  3       11
3      3  1       18  2       16  3       13"

data <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```